# Do two conditional updates in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a beginner in OracleSQL and I have to

- set a value to 0 when another value is null and
- set the value to 1 when the other value is not null.

Currently, I do 2 SQL queries.

```
UPDATE UTDIM SET RESULTAT = 1 where utdim.ut_idt in (select b.ut_idt from blockut b, ut u where b.block_idt = 1333864 and u.idt = b.ut_idt and u.pileut is null)
UPDATE UTDIM SET RESULTAT = 0 where utdim.ut_idt in (select b.ut_idt from blockut b, ut u where b.block_idt = 1333864 and u.idt = b.ut_idt and u.pileut is not null)
```

Is that possible to do with only 1 SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, maybe not Oracle-code, but it should now work (after some assistance...):

```
UPDATE UTDIM SET RESULTAT = (select case when u.pileut is null then 1 else 0 end
                             from blockut b, ut u
                             where b.block_idt = 1333864
                               and u.idt = b.ut_idt
                               and b.ut_idt = utdim.ut_idt)
where utdim.ut_idt in (select b.ut_idt from blockut b, ut u
                       where b.block_idt = 1333864
                         and u.idt = b.ut_idt)
```

Comment: I think you are missing a condition in the subquery used in the `SET` clause, e.g., `b.ut_idt = utdim.ut_idt` *or* `u.idt = utdim.ut_idt`

Comment: Oops. Thank you for the comment, will soon edit. (I'm so ashamed...)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things here:

1. Update only records for which you find a match in your subquery (i.e. where a blockut with block_idt = 1333864 and a ut with the same idt exist).
2. Set resultat to 1 or 0 according to the found pileut.

This would be

```
update utdim 
set resultat = 
case when 
(
  select u.pileut 
  from blockut b 
  join ut u on u.idt = b.ut_idt 
  where b.ut_idt = utdim.ut_idt
  and b.block_idt = 1333864
) is null then 1 else 0 end
where exists
(
  select *
  from blockut b 
  join ut u on u.idt = b.ut_idt 
  where b.ut_idt = utdim.ut_idt
  and b.block_idt = 1333864
);
```

As you can see this is doing the same thing twice (doppeltgemoppelt as we Germans say). You'd use the same subquery to determine which records to update *and* with which value to update. This can be done with an updatable query instead. If Oracle considers below query updatable, then it will work, otherwise you'll get an error.

```
update  
(
  select utdim.resultat, u.pileut 
  from utdim
  join blockut b on b.ut_idt = utdim.ut_idt and b.block_idt = 1333864
  join ut u on u.idt = b.ut_idt 
)
set resultat = case when pileut is null then 1 else 0 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this in a single update statement:

```
UPDATE utdim utd
   SET utd.resultat = ( SELECT CASE WHEN u.pileut IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
                          FROM ut u, blockut b
                         WHERE u.idt = utd.ut_idt
                           AND u.idt = b.ut_idt
                           AND b.block_idt = 1333864 )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ut u, blockut b
                 WHERE u.idt = utd.ut_idt
                   AND u.idt = b.ut_idt
                   AND b.block_idt = 1333864 );
```

I *think* I have the joins correct above.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's possible. Something like

```
update utdim u set 
  resultat = nvl2(
    (select u.pileut 
     from blockut b 
     where b.block_idt = 1333864 and u.idt = b.ut_idt), 
  1, 0)
```

Comment: But wont this query update all rows of the table, not only those found by the sub-query?

Comment: You must filter the rows that should be updated, not all rows needs to be updated.

Comment: It would. We don't know what relation between these tables, so I preferred to show the main idea.